# Locations for new crew members

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Where can I find a list of new people to recruit for the heists? I know at least one is available from a random encounter, I'm wondering how many there are total, and where they are located?

Comment: I've not seen a list but can tell you from playing it through that you get a few just by following the story.  I only had 1 through a random encounter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get 2 new crew member from random encounters:

- *Packie McReary* from *GTA IV*, a highly skilled gunman.
- *Taliana Martinez*, a highly skilled yet *very cheap* driver (definitely get her!)

Where to find them: Every copy of *GTA 5* should be shipped with a map, we'll be using that map to locate them. **Packie** can be found in **South Los Santos** by the clothing store at H3 on the map.
**Taliana** is on the **Great Ocean Highway** in **Blaine County** at B5, where the highway and the railway intersect.

Keep in mind that since these are random encounters, there is a chance that their encounter will *not* trigger even as you approach the area.

---

You get 2 new crew member from doing regular missions.:

- *Rickie Luckens*, a cheap and low-skilled hacker. Available after he calls Michael after completing the mission *Friend Request*. But also if you do the first heist with him or any other low skilled, low cut crew members they will gain skill and still take the same cut that he has started with in other heist(Jobs).
- *Chef*, a highly skilled gunman. Available after he calls Trevor after completing the mission *Trevor Philips Industries*.

Comment: Those are the only 4 I know of. Feel free to complete the list, if there are more.

Comment: What happens with the map if you buy GTA on steam?

Comment: @Andalur - GTA5 has not been released for PC yet.  The map is going to be exactly the same though.